# Block Third Party URL or Inspectors in Shopify Store

Tags: javascript, shopify, google-chrome-app, web-development-server

Trying to Block Chrome Extensions like commerce inspector from My Shopify Store. This code runs perfectly on another store but it's now working correctly on my **Shopify Store**.

```
var junk_sites = ["app.commerceinspector.com","pexda.com","ecomhunt.com","dropship-spy.com","ehproductfinder.com","dropshippinggenesis.com","productmafia.com","e-sniper.com","drospy.com","anon.to","shoptrace.co","smartadfinder.com","nullrefer.com","upwork.com","nichescraper.com","salessource.io","fbcandy.com","easyali.com"];
        junk_sites.forEach(function(v){
            if( document.referrer.indexOf(v) != -1 ) {
                document.location.href =  parseURL('https://' + window.location.hostname);
            }
        });
```

**Does anyone know how to block these urls without using php in Shopify best Shopify doesn't support PHP.**

Comment: You cannot block URLs. Shopify is a hosted service, and they accept incoming requests on your behalf.

Comment: Kindly try to explain your question in more detail. What is hapnnening? Do you get an error? What are the links looking like.hat should they look like? I suppose you wanted to say "not" instead of "now". Please correct that, if so.

Comment: How to block Chrome Extensions to have any impact on your website. I used content-security-policy but it block some of my own scripts.